# Iphone - how to pass a parameter to animationDidStop?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have this method...

```
- (void) helloThere: (int) myValue {

  // I am trying to pass myValue to animationDidStop
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:[NSNumber numberWithInt: myValue]];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
  [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
  [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

  // do stuff

  [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

then I am trying to retrieve myValue on animationDidStop...

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {

  int retrievedValue = (int)context; //??? not giving me the right number

}
```

but retrievedValue is giving me a number that has nothing to do to the original myValue...

How to retrieve that number?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [@DyingCactus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297354/iphone-how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-animationdidstop/2297426#2297426)'s answer for how to get the integer.

OP's code, however, has a serious problem on the context. Since the type of context is `void*`, UIKit will not expect you to pass an ObjC object into it, so the NSNumber will not be retained.

Therefore, when you perform

```
[(NSNumber*)context intValue];
```

in animationDidStop it's almost certain that you'll get some crazy numbers or crash.

There are 2 similar ways to solve this problem.

**(a)** Pass the object with retain count of +1, and release it in animationDidStop:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:myValue]];
....
int retrievedValue = [(NSNumber*)context intValue];
[(NSNumber*)context release];
```

**(b)** Pass a `malloc`-ed memory, and `free` it in animationDidStop:

```
int* c = malloc(sizeof(*c));
*c = myValue;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:c];
....
int retrievedValue = *(int*)context;
free(context);
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.

Comment: Just curious: I don't see a selector named animationDidStop:finished:context: in the documentation. I see animationDidStop:finished: selector, but its signature is different, where the animation is a CAAnimation and the finished is a BOOL - the one in the question passes an NSString for an animation id and a number for finished and a void * for context. Am I missing something in the documentation??

Comment: Oh, I see. I was looking at the wrong method. The one I saw was on NSObject, and the one I was looking for is on UIView. Thanks.

Comment: Think I've been doing it wrong all this time... see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297752/setting-animationdidstopselector-on-uiviews-animation-delegate

Comment: Don't forget to add __bridge cast if you using ARC. 
`[UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:(__bridge void *)@"test"];`
and in handler:
`[(__bridge NSString *)context isEqualToString:@"test"]`

Answer (score 3):

You are putting an NSNumber in context so retrieve it like this:

```
int retrievedValue = [(NSNumber *)context intValue];
```